# Is it possible to use css to activate hover state for self and children but not parent of the same class?

Tags: css

The only way I could see this being possible with css is to somehow use the :not selector, but I can't figure it out. The comments below illustrate what hover state should be active when a mouse-over occurs.

```
<div class='node'> // node is activated
  <div class='node'></div> // node is activated but parent is de-activated
  <div class='node'> // node and children are activated but parent is de-activated
    <div class='node'>
      <div class='node'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/tGNAAPJ9vKedvy3yjmQk

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700783/css-how-to-apply-childhover-but-not-parenthover) but probably not as you asked.

Comment: [This may give you an idea](http://plnkr.co/edit/wg2yOWnvIxJsUnXU5BqG?p=preview).

Comment: The simple answer is no, not with current CSS.  The problem here is CSS currently has no way of moving "up a level" in your selector path.  Essentially you can't just do .child:hover .parent {}  In level4 css selectors I believe there are plans for selector like the descendent child selector that performs essentially the opposite function.  I can't confirm this though and even if it did exist it will have 0 support at this time.  You best solution is javascript.

Comment: yeah, without a [parent selector](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/1937302), I can't see how you'd make this work.