# How to change parent on child hover?

Tags: css, mouseover

I know this could be done with jQuery relatively easy but I'm looking for a CSS solution if anybody can help me.

[**I've fiddled what I have here:**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25308213/css-change-parent-on-child-hover#25308213)

Essentially what I want to do is when a span is hovered, it changes the parent div's background.  `#testBanner`

This is what I've tried - And it obviously doesn't look right, at least from my point of view it doesn't.  But I can't think of any other way to do it.

```
#testBanner .hover-1:hover #testBanner {background: #EEFFEE;}
```

Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately there is no "parent selector".  At least not yet.  There is a relatively decent hack to work around it using "the checkbox hack".  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393931/faking-the-parent-selector-using-pure-css

Comment: You can[TRY THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22270078/css-hover-on-a-div-but-not-if-hover-on-his-children) else [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393931/faking-the-parent-selector-using-pure-css)