# Simulate mouseenter with pure css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to style an element when I hover with the mouse above it. But, I don't want to style its parent DOM elements. However, when I use `:hover` the element in question is styled just as I want, but unfortunately, all of its parents are styled too

```
*:hover {
    border-color: red;
}
```

[image]

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/7L80wcq2/3/)

```css
main,
article,
div {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 30px;
}

*:hover {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article>
    <div>

    </div>
  </article>
</main>
```

The outer border shall be red only if the cursor is between the outer border and the middle border. The middle order shall be red only if the cursor is between the middle border and the inner border. The inner border shall be red only if the cursor is inside the inner border.

Is there a way to only style the DOM element being hovered (which can be any element)? or can I only achieve this goal with javascript?

Comment: Your demo does not match your sample so I added it here - you do realize it is doing exactly what you specified? You told the parents to also style on hover.  Please specify which of the child elements you wish to style.

Comment: What is the JavaScript code you are trying to recreate?

Comment: Do you want this to apply to all elements, but not affect parent elements? Because that has been somewhat covered here: [CSS hover on a div, but not if hover on his children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22270078/css-hover-on-a-div-but-not-if-hover-on-his-children) (though the top answer is of limited usefulness depending on your use-case)

Comment: I have added the following sentence: "The outer border shall be red only if the cursor is between the outer border and the middle border. The middle order shall be red only if the cursor is between the middle border and the inner border. The inner border shall be red only if the cursor is inside the inner border."

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700783/how-to-apply-childhover-but-not-parenthover

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't avoid the parent `:hover` with pure CSS today. There are quite a few topics on SO discussing this:

[How to apply child:hover but not parent:hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700783/how-to-apply-childhover-but-not-parenthover)

Safari has introduced support for a `:has` parent selector, and might solve this if other browsers support it as well. But it's still not a viable option today.

You asked if you can achieve this with javascript, and yes you can hack a solution in javascript using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, toggling a CSS class.

https://jsfiddle.net/sq1kcwdt/4/

[image]

Comment: The solution is great... but what about the pure CSS part?

Comment: @カメロン It can't be done, as already widely discussed on other SO questions. The OP asked "or can I only achieve this goal with javascript?" and that's where I'm trying to help. If the original goal isn't possible, it can be useful to show alternatives, no?

Comment: Zoltan has demonstrated that it can be done with pure CSS, see his answer.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl His alternative is fun, though not working for me (top-level element still has a red border when I hover over the center element). Overlaying a second absolutely-positioned border is similar to other HTML approaches with absolutely positioned divs. It's worth considering as a hack, but by no means a pure CSS "solution" to avoiding the :hover of a parent element.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it's possible with some tricks using `::before` or `::after`. You can use these pseudo-elements to cover up the borders you want. It's important to use pointer-events: none; on these elements, so they won't disturb anything, they are just there for decoration.

However, my opinion is that javascript is more effective in this use case.

Here is a quick solution you can check out:
https://codepen.io/serazoltan/pen/WNXOREq

It needs a lot of updates for general use, but I've made it just to show it's possible.

```css
:root {
  --general-padding: 30px;
  --general-padding-neg: -33px;
}

main,
article,
div {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: var(--general-padding);
  position: relative;
  transition: all .3s;
}

main {
  height: 400px;
  z-index: 0;
}

article {
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 10;
}

div {
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 20;
}

main:hover {
  border-color: red;
}

article:hover {
  border-color: red;
}

article:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--general-padding-neg);
  left: var(--general-padding-neg);
  width: calc(100% + var(--general-padding)*2 + 4px);
  height: 460px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  pointer-events: none;
}

div:hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
  z-index: 20;
}

div:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--general-padding-neg);
  left: var(--general-padding-neg);
  width: calc(100% + var(--general-padding)*2 + 4px);
  height: 260px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your CSS ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sb8kLz7g/)):

```css
div:hover {
    border-color: red;
}
```

Alternatively, add a class to elements you want to share a common style ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ps2axem5/)).

```html
<main>
  <article>
    <div class="highlight-on-hover">

    </div>
    <div>

    </div>
    <div class="highlight-on-hover">

    </div>
  </article>
</main>
```

```css
.highlight-on-hover:hover {
    border-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I shouldn't just work for that div (that was just an example). But it should work for any element

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri Yep so you can add a class to your elements, then the associated styles will be applied. I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

```css
main,
article,
div {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 30px;
}

div:hover {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article>
    <div id='myDiv'>

    </div>
  </article>
</main>
```

Comment: My code was just an example, I guess I wasn't clear. So, it should work for any element, not just that div

Answer (score 1):

Just taking a guess with the ambiguous question example.  You can say what NOT to style as well. You said "all" with `*:hover` so it does that.

```css
main,
article,
div {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 30px;
}

*:hover:not(.not-me) {
  border-color: red;
}

main:hover:not(.not-me) {
  border-color: green;
}

article:hover:not(.not-me) {
  border-color: blue;
}

main>article>div:hover:not(.not-me) {
  border-color: inherit;
  border-color: orange;
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

main.not-me:hover:not(*),
main.not-me *.not-me *:hover:not(*) {}
```

```html
<main>
  <article>
    <div>

    </div>
    <div class="not-me">
      not me
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="not-me">
    <div>
      not me either, I am inside not-me
    </div>
    <div class="not-me">
      not me
    </div>
  </article>
</main>
<main class="not-me">
  nothing in here
  <article class="not-me">
    <div>
      ME I want in also!
    </div>
    <div>
      ME!
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="not-me">
    <div>
      Me ME! I am inside not-me
    </div>
    <div class="not-me">
      not me
    </div>
  </article>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are applying the :hover to all elements on the page by using the *-selector, you can read more about that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors

Make it more specific by selecting the div:

```css
div:hover {
  /* your rules here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this code:

```
$("main, article, div").hover(function () {
      $(this).parent().css('border-color', 'lightgrey');
}, function () {
      $(this).parent().css('border-color', '');
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).