# Apply hover style to any child but not parent

Tags: css, css-selectors, hover

I am building a tool that requires the user to click/select an element on the page. The page content/structure/css is not known.

I am using javascript mouse enter/leave events to add/remove an outline class to the element and show the user what they are selecting. However, the events are unreliable and the outlined element not always the one that is clicked.

Adding the style with `:hover` css is much faster and more reliable.

Is there a way to outline any hovered elements, but none of its parents?

One way is to do:

`*:hover { outline: 1px solid green; }`

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGvXbm

But this will outline every parent of the element.

Is there a way to exclude parents from this selector?

Comment: Nope....sorry. If you're hovering a child, you're hovering the parent.

Comment: Try to check this answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2701495/3340702

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS How to apply child:hover but not parent:hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700783/css-how-to-apply-childhover-but-not-parenthover)

Comment: Can you stop the hover event from propagating? Or is there some selector that will get only the element you're on?

Comment: This is not possible in CSS. Each child element is inside the parent, therefore when you are hovering over a child, you are also hovering over all of its parents. This may be possible in Javascript however...

Comment: It is possible in Javascript (well, I did it in jQuery, but it should be easily convertible). Check out my answer and this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKOemr)

Answer (score 1):

```
:hover * { outline: 1px solid green; }
```

That is, find any elements that are hovered and apply this style to all children.

Comment: Using this method, the style is applied to every element on the page when the body is hovered

Comment: If you want to only select element from within the body you can you `body :hover *`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by making the 2(or more divs) siblings instead of descendents. And then positioning them absolutely.
Now if you apply hover to them then it will work independently as they are not inherited by each other.

For example:

```
<div class="one">
</div>
<div class="two">
</div>
<div class="three">
</div>
```

And then css

```
 *:hover {
   outline: 3px solid red;
  }

 .two, .three {

  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you can do the following:

```
$('*').hover(
  function() {
    $('*').css('outline', 'none')
    $(this).css('outline', '3px solid red')
  },
  function() {
    $(this).css('outline', 'none')
  }
)
```

You do have to also remove the `:hover` CSS rule.
Check out the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKOemr) as well as the snippet below.

Note that only seems to work when entering the element, when leaving you would have to have a `.mousemove()` function and detect if the mouse is over the element, then repeat the code in the first `.hover()` function.

```js
$('*').hover(
  function() {
    $('*').css('outline', 'none')
    $(this).css('outline', '3px solid red')
  },
  function() {
    $(this).css('outline', 'none')
  }
)
```

```css
/* *:hover {
  outline: 3px solid red;
} */

.one {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: green;
}

.two {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.three {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <div class="three"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
  </div>
</div>
```